# Как сделать так, чтобы в форме отрабатывали две кнопки с разным функционалом

Tags: html, jsp

Есть вот такая вот форма для поиска данных, но проблема в том что вторая кнопка "Удалить фильтр" отрабатывает так-же как и первая(то есть делает тоже поиск, а должна его чистить), если ее вынести за форму, она отрабатывает правильно, но нужно что бы она была именно в форме, подскажите в чем проблема.

```
    <form  class=" form-inline searchTmi pull-left" style="padding-right: 5px;" method="get" name="frm" action="SearchSki">

     <div class="form-group">
     <label>Номер замовлення</label> <input type="text" size="10px" name="nzak" value="${nzak}" id="nzak" align="middle" placeholder="Номер">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
     <label>Виріб</label> <input type="text" size="10px" name="kiz" value="${kiz}" id="kiz" align="middle" placeholder="Код">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
     <label>Позначення</label> <input type="text" size="26px" name="osd" value="${osd}" id="osd" align="middle" placeholder="Позначення">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
     <label>Пріоритет</label> <input type="text" size="10px" name="pri" value="${pri}" id="pri" align="middle" placeholder="Пріоритет">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
     <label>Найменування</label> <input type="text" size="40px" name="naim" value="${naim}" id="naim" align="middle" placeholder="Найменування">
     </div>

     <!--Выполнить фильтр-->
     <div class="form-group">
     <button id="filtAccept" class="btnCollor btn  btn-md btn-success" 
             data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Виконати 
             фільтр"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>
     </div>
      <!--Удалить фильтр-->                               
     <div class="form-group">
     <a class="pull-left" href="SearchSki?page=1&count=0&nzak=&kiz=&osd=&pri=&naim=&pages=${pages}">
     <button type="submit" class="btnCollor btn  btn-md btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Відмінити фільтр">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></a>
     </div>
</form>
```

Comment: попытался сделать так  `<input id="searchClear" class="btn btn-warning btn-md" 
                                       type="button"  
                                       onclick="window.location.href = 'SearchSki?page=1&count=0&nzak=&kiz=&osd=&pri=&naim=&pages=${pages}'" />` но так не получается добавить Глификон, может кто знает как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию, если Вы вставляете в форму ссылку/кнопку она сабмитит форму. Вам нужно просто использовать `<button type="button">картинки/теги/ текст</button>`.Если Вам нужно очистить форму, то подойдет `type="reset"`.

Comment: Спасибо, работает с `button type="button"`